# Use a script to check the size of regular files in my home directory greater or equal to 1KB

Tags: linux, bash, unix

As the title says I'm currently having difficulty checking for files exclusively in my home directory.

Simply my current script is as follows
  #!/bin/sh
  echo `find ~/ -type f -size +1023c -print`

That does display the files that are over 1kb but it does it for all folders in my home directory. Any and all tips are welcomed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1023c -print
```

from man page:

```
-maxdepth levels
     Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of
     directories below the command line arguments.  -maxdepth 0
     means only apply the tests and actions to the command line
     arguments.
```

Comment: I've gotten a little further into the problem and the next step is to back up (the files found this way) to a compressed file using .bak 

Current code is 

http://pastebin.com/fb7c9yjn

Comment: `find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1023c  ! -name '*.bak' -print | xargs gzip --keep --suffix .bak` this will skip *.bak files and will compress others, also it will keep the originals. Did not test it myself but it should work.

Comment: Also a hint: if you add -P<number> (e.g. -P5) to xargs, it will use <number> processes in parallel. This will speed up compression on multicore systems.

Comment: Alright I picked up an old book and figured it out. for all those curious http://pastebin.com/gGXZQr7U is how i got it working.